# Powerapps : is it possible to geolocate user via Android?

Tags: geolocation, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I'm building an PowerApps application. I would like to know if is it possible to geolocate an user whose using my PowerApps Application. For example, i want to create a button, and when user click on this button, the geolocation will be activated and the user's position archivated in my apps. Is it possible ?
Thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

**Location**

The Location signal returns the location of the device based on the Global Positioning System (GPS) and other device information, such as cell-tower communications and IP address.

*When a user accesses the location information for the first time, the device may prompt that user to allow access to this information.*

As the location changes, dependencies on the location will continuously recalculate, which will consume power from the device's battery. To conserve battery life, you can use the Enable and Disable functions to turn location updates on and off. Location is automatically turned off if the displayed screen doesn't depend on location information.

**Location.Altitude**   Returns a number that indicates the altitude, measured in feet, above sea level.

**Location.Latitude**   Returns a number, from -90 to 90, that indicates the latitude, as measured in degrees from the equator. A positive number indicates a location that's north of the equator.

**Location.Longitude**  Returns a number, from 0 to 180, that indicates the longitude, as measured in degrees west from Greenwich, England.

From Microsofts own documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/signals#location